# Printing out datatypes

Tags: java, types

I have the following code:

```
class Solution{
public static void main(String []argh){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);   
        try
        {
            long x=sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
            if(x>=-128 && x<=127)System.out.println("* byte");
            if(x>=-32768 && x<=32767)System.out.println("* short");
            // The following two lines will be replaced:
            if(x>=Math.pow(-2,31) && x<=Math.pow(2,31)-1)System.out.println("* int");
            if(x>=Math.pow(-2,63) && x<=Math.pow(2,63)-1)System.out.println("* long");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
        }

    }
}
```

**Input:** 
9223372036854775807

**Output:**
9223372036854775807 can be fitted in:
* long

If I modify the two marked lines to this:

```
if(x>=(int)Math.pow(-2,31) && x<=(int)Math.pow(2,31)-1)System.out.println("* int");
if(x>=(long)Math.pow(-2,63) && x<=(long)Math.pow(2,63)-1)System.out.println("* long");
```

So the whole code will look like this:

```
class Solution{
public static void main(String []argh){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        try
        {
            long x=sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
            if(x>=-128 && x<=127)System.out.println("* byte");
            if(x>=-32768 && x<=32767)System.out.println("* short");
            //The following two line have been replaced. 
            if(x>=(int)Math.pow(-2,31) && x<=(int)Math.pow(2,31)-1)System.out.println("* int");
            if(x>=(long)Math.pow(-2,63) && x<=(long)Math.pow(2,63)-1)System.out.println("* long");
            //
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
        }

    }
}
```

If the input is the same, the output will be different.

**Input:** 
9223372036854775807

**Output:**
9223372036854775807 can be fitted in:

It doesn't print out: *long

What is the reason of this?

Comment: For the love of coffee, please use some `{}`, indentation, line breaks, ...

Comment: Also, if it doesn't execute the body of your `if`, then probably because the condition evaluated to `false`.

Comment: Have you debugged this? Which part of your `if` condition is evaluating false? What are the numbers in the condition actually evaluating to?

Comment: hint: let's say `x = 9223372036854775807`. print out the following values: `double upperDouble = Math.pow(2, 63) - 1; long upperWrong = (long) Math.pow(2, 63) - 1; long upperLong = (long) upperDouble;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening due to a combination of two things:

- casts having a higher precedence than subtraction in java.
- java yielding Long.MAX_VALUE when you try to convert to `long` a `double` value which is too large to fit in a `long`.

So, this expression: `(long)Math.pow(2,63)-1` computes two to the 63rd power, giving a number which is not representable in `long`.  Then it casts this to `long`, giving you Long.MAX_VALUE.  But then it subtracts one from it, giving you a value which is smaller than what you want.

The following:

```
    System.out.printf("%15f\n", Math.pow(2, 63));
    System.out.printf("%15d\n", (long) Math.pow(2, 63));
    System.out.printf("%15d\n", (long) Math.pow(2, 63) - 1);
    System.out.printf("%15d\n", (long) (Math.pow(2, 63) - 1));
```

Yields this:

```
9223372036854776000.000000 <-- inaccurate due to `double` being lossy
9223372036854775807 <-- Long.MAX_VALUE (what you really want)
9223372036854775806 <-- you subtracted one, so this is what you get
9223372036854775807 <-- what you also really want.
```

In light of the fact that Long.MAX_VALUE does not appear to be accurately representable in `double`, I would advise that you refrain from trying to derive `Long.MAX_VALUE` using `double` arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks! I can see it now?

Comment: One more question: in this case shouldn't the input  9223372036854775807 catched as an exception and make the output:
9223372036854775807  can't be fitted anywhere ?

Comment: Well, as I said, casting a `double` to `long` will ***not*** throw an exception if the `double` does not fit in a `long`; instead, it returns `Long.MAX_VALUE`.  That's by design.  You could argue that it should not be so by design, but that would be a philosophical discussion.

Answer (score 0):

use below code.

```
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try
    {
        int x=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
        if(x>=-128 && x<=127)System.out.println("* byte");
        else if(x>=-32768 && x<=32767)System.out.println("* short");
        //The following two line have been replaced. 
        else if(x>=(int)Math.pow(-2,31) && x<=(int)Math.pow(2,31)-1)System.out.println("* int");
        else if(x>=(long)Math.pow(-2,63) && x<=(long)Math.pow(2,63)-1)System.out.println("* long");
        //
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
    }
```

Comment: ((long)Math.pow(2,63)-1) gives the value 9223372036854775806 .so how can say that 9223372036854775807 is <= 9223372036854775806

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong a number say 332323232 is integer type,23L (instead of small) is of long datatype because of L after it.
Yes you said the truth that it does not print *long when you input 9223372036854775807[ (2^63)-1] in second case and moreover if you will enter 1L or L then it will simply print  can't be fitted anywhere.
That's the second bug.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
if ((x >= (long)Math.pow(-2, 63)) && (x <= (long)(Math.pow(2, 63) - 1)))
    System.out.println("* long");
```

This produces the output:

```
9223372036854775807 can be fitted in:
* long
```

A more readable way would be to write

```
if (x >= Long.MIN_VALUE && x <= Long.MAX_VALUE) 
    System.out.println("* long");
```

which prints the same result